# Replace a line starting with '-' hyphen with a character repeated n times

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file that has some lines like this (hyphen repeated)

```
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to replace these lines with character 'B' repeated 1500 times. For example, like

`BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB`

Any suggestions using 'sed' or 'awk' command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```sh
$ awk '/^-+$/ {s = sprintf("% 1500s", ""); gsub(/ /,"B",s); print s; next} 1' file
```

Or, maybe a bit more efficient if you have many such lines:

```sh
$ awk 'BEGIN {s = sprintf("% 1500s", ""); gsub(/ /,"B",s)} \
       /^-+$/ {print s; next} 1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
perl -pe 'my $bb = "B"x1500; s/^-+$/$bb/g'
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

printf+sed variant:

```
$ cat file
1111
----
2222

$ sed -r 's/^-+$/'"$(printf --  "%.1s" B{1..150})/" file
1111
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
2222
```

Here sed is used only for replacement.
printf is used for generating 1500 times B. (The above scriptlet has 150 instead of 1500, because it required too much scrolling.)